# Attempting to replace a word that consists of nodes in a linked list in C

Tags: c

I am attempting to find a lists of nodes which form a word in a linked list. So it goes something like: `I->a->n-> ->i->s-> ->a->w-e>s->o->m->e->NULL`. The goal is to replace it with something like `I->a->n-> ->i->s-> ->c->o->o->l->NULL`. We want to do this irrespective of the size of the word being replaced or the word replacing it.

I've attempted to loop through index and delete the word and then replace it via index. However, this creates complicates things and I never truly get the word that I am seeking.

I am now simply trying to delete the word that is to be replaced and now I'm trying to simply replace the words for by the nodes with new nodes that form new words.

I am now attempting to manipulate the array size to see if this allows me to put a word through.

```
void indexInsert(char character, int n){

    node* temp1 =(node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp1->character = character;
    temp1->nextNode = NULL;
    if(n == 1){
        temp1->nextNode = headNode;
        headNode = temp1;
        return;
    }
    node* temp2 = headNode;
    for(int i = 0; i < n-2; i++){
        temp2 = temp2->nextNode;
    }

    temp1->nextNode = temp2->nextNode;
    temp2->nextNode = temp1;

}

void replaceWord(char replaceWord[]) {

    deleteWord(&headNode, replaceWord);

    int Size = 1;
    int Size2 = 2;
    char entryWord[Size];
    char entryWordCopy[Size2];

    printf("Please enter the new word you wish to insert: ");
    strcpy_s(entryWordCopy, Size2,gets_s(entryWord, Size));
    printf("\n");

    int length = strlen(entryWordCopy);

    indexInsert(entryWordCopy, length);

    Print(head);



}
```

The end result should be the removal of the nodes that form word A, and subsequently being replaced by the nodes that form word B. However, upon executing the program, I run into problems with my size arrays and my strings not evaluated. Reports back: failure was caused by a read of a variable outside of its lifetime.

Comment: "*I am now simply trying to delete the word that is to be replaced and now I'm trying to simply replace the words for by the nodes with new nodes that form new words*" -- that sounds like a good approach to me.

Comment: First off, turn up your compiler warnings and pay attention to them.  You have at least one argument type mismatch that will certainly cause you grief, and any decent compiler ought to be able to diagnose that for you.

Comment: As for using an object past its lifetime, I don't see any reason in the code presented to expect an error of that particular kind, though I see ways that such a thing could happen with small variations in that code.  I'm not about to write an answer pertaining to a problem that some random variation of your code would have, however.  Please, if resolving your compilation warnings leaves you with issues then present a *bona fide* [mcve] that demonstrates the problem(s) you're asking about.

Comment: Do you want to change the word, which follows "Ian is"?

Comment: I want to be able to change is. So Ian was cool. Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

**My tip:**
Do not use indices with lists, you can do the same thing with pointers to the nodes. You do not have to iterate to the index, pointers to the nodes are faster.

You should change the algorithms to use pointers to nodes:

**Finding the last word:**
You iterate through the list, if you find a node which is a space, you store the pointer to that node in a variable, if you reached the end of the list, the remembered pointer to the node, is the space before the last word. You just have to change the following nodes. If you never found a node, which contains a space, you can simply replace the whole list, with the replacement.

Another trick is to use double pointers, which stores the pointer to the pointer, which points to the node of the last word. (This might also be the root of the list)

```
// node** p is a pointer to the pointer of the first element
// if your root is defined as `node* root`, you use
// `... = last_word(&root);`
node** last_word(node** p) {
    node* n = *p;
    while(n) {
        if(n->data == ' ') p = &n->next;
        n = n->next;
    };
    return p;
};
```

**Inserting a node:**

You got a pointer from an algorithm like `last_word`, which is a pointer to a pointer to a node. It points to the variable, which stores the pointer to the next node (There is a ComputerPhile video about this), this fully handels insertion at the beginning, end and in the middle:

```
void insert(node** p, char c) {
    node* elem = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    elem->data = c;
    elem->next = *p; // connect to following node
    *p = elem; // connect previous node/root to the node
};
```

**And if you really need to work with indices**, you should split always split the code up into seperate functions.

```
node** node_by_index(node** p, int index) {
    while(index > 0) {
        p = &(*p)->next;
        --index;
    };
    return p;
};
```

Comment: I'm trying to add this word at any point on the list. I'm not simply trying to add to the end.

Comment: Your example looks as if you want to **replace** the last word.

Comment: No, the indexinsert is supposed to be able to be replaced at nth index.

Comment: How would I go about checking that I am replaces all instances of the word I'd like to replace?